# Measure the overhead of context switching in GPU

Tags: cuda, gpu, overhead, context-switch

There are a lot of ways to measure the CPU context switching overhead. It seems it has few resources to measure the GPU context switching overhead. The CPU context switching and GPU's are quite different.

The GPU scheduling is based on warp scheduling. To calculate the overhead of GPU context switching, I need to know the time of warp with context switching and warp without context switching, and do the subtraction to get the overhead.

I am confused about how to measure the time of warp with context switching? Does anyone have some ideas to measure?

Comment: CUDA has multiple different levels of context switching. Cost to do full GPU context switch is 25-50µs. Cost to launch CUDA thread block is 100s of cycles. Cost to launch CUDA warps is < 10 cycles. Cost to switch between warps allocated to a warp scheduler is 0 cycles and can happen every cycle. The cost of CDP SW pre-emption on CC>=3.5 is higher and varies with GPU workload.

Comment: Thanks a lot. According to Fermi whitepaper, it says "The Fermi pipeline is optimized to reduce the cost of an application context switch to below 25 microseconds ". Is this 25 microseconds the full GPU context switch as you said? I am confused about the cost to switch between warps. Suppose warp A accesses global memory, and it has hundreds cycles latency. At this time, warp scheduler switches another warp to make the ALUs busy. Does the warp switch have 0 cycle or is it possible that it has some amount of cycles for the scheduler to do the warp switching.

Comment: There is no context switching for warps. When a block is rasterized into warps the warps are assigned to a warp scheduler and all registers are allocated. The warp scheduler maintains a list of eligible warps (not stalled). On each clock cycle it can issue from any eligible warp with 0 overhead. There is no data to be context switched. All hardware resources have already been assigned to the warp so there is no data to switch.

Comment: Thanks. Greg. Your answer is very informative and correct some fallacies. Even though we know for sure that the warp switching time is 0, I was wondering if we can design a test to see the time of warp switching, and test whether the time is zero or not by ourselves.

Comment: If you execute a dependent arithmetic operation in a tight loop (e.g. value *= iteration where value is a float you are creating a chain of dependent instructions. If the loop iterations are constant you can unroll the loop. Execute this kernel with 4 warps/SM then 8 warps/SM, ... The scheduler will be forced between instructions to switch warps. You should find that each warp scheduler can issue an instruction every cycle. Alternatively, you can write a program that does a long chain of clock() reads then writes out the results to a different address per warp then sort the warp IDs.

Comment: Greg. Thanks for your gold comment. I wonder if you can post your comment as an answer.  Thus I can accept your answer and mark the question solved.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it really makes sense to talk about "overhead" of context switching on a GPU.

On a CPU, context switching is done in software, by a function in the kernel called a "scheduler".  The scheduler is ordinary code, a sequence of machine instructions that the processor has to run, and time spent running the scheduler is time not spent doing "useful" work.

A GPU, on the other hand, does context switching in hardware, without a scheduler, and it's fast enough that when one task encounters a pipeline stall, another task can be brought in to utilize the pipeline stages that would otherwise be idle.  This is called "latency hiding" — delays in one task are hidden by progress in other tasks.  The context switches actually allow *more* useful work to be done in a given timeframe.

For more information, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/471595/20703) I wrote to a related question on SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks a lot. GPU uses context switching to hide the latency to have more throughput. To be more specific, I want to measure the time taken to switch one task to another task. Suppose task A (or warp A) have a pipeline stall or long memory access, GPU schedules task B (or warp B) to hide the latency caused by task A. My question is how to measure the time taken on a GPU to switch task A to task B. The context switching time definitely has some value even though it is very small. That's what I want to measure.

Comment: The context switch time is zero when measured in gpu clock cycles.

Comment: The interesting "context switch" time for GPUs is between CUDA contexts, not thread contexts.

Comment: I would mention that **hyper threading** on CPUs is somewhat similar to the warp scheduling on GPUs: If one thread blocks on a memory read then the other thread can utilize the rest of the core to do its own progress. This fine-grained "context switching" is also maintained by hardware at no overhead.